# Make a custom listView for fragments?

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, tabs, android-fragments

I trying to build an app with 4 tabs. Every tab has a different fragment linked to it. The issue is that I want to make a custom listView for each fragment, but it ends with some unsolvable error... I have talked to other developers, but I still can't make one that works! It's really frustrating!

**I have:**

- A MainActivity class that works, it uses swipe-able tabs
- An XML with the design I want on my custom ListView.
- An XML called fragment1 with a ListView.

**These are normal errors I get:**

- "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type Fragment1UG"
- "The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type Fragment1UG. 1 quick fix available: Create method 'setContentView()'"

One of the guides I'm trying to understand and use:

- [Android ListView Tutorial](http://javatechig.com/android/android-listview-tutorial/#3_Building_ListViewusing_Custom_Adapter)
- [Android ListFragment Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

This is my 1st fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Fragment1test extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            //This layout contains your list view 
                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

               //now you must initialize your list view
                ListView yourListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
                ListView.setAdapter(new ListAdapter());
              return view;
    }
}
```

My ListAdapter.java code (from a tutorial):

```
import java.util.List;

import android.content.ClipData.Item;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

private List<Item> items;

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {

    super(context, resource, items);

    this.items = items;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_design, null);

    }

    Item p = items.get(position);

    if (p != null) {

        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_txtTitle);
        TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_txtRelease);
        TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.game_txtPlatform);

        if (tt != null) {
            tt.setText(p.getId());
        }
        if (tt1 != null) {

            tt1.setText(p.getCategory().getId());
        }
        if (tt3 != null) {

            tt3.setText(p.getDescription());
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is this ListAdapter()?? where is the code for that??

Comment: see my edit in answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public class Fragment1test extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        //This layout contains your list view 
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_basic, container, false);

           //now you must initialize your list view
           ListView listview =(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.your_listview);

           //EDITED Code 
           String[] items = new String[] {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
           new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items); 

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);  

            //To have custom list view use this : you must define CustomeAdapter class
            // listview.setadapter(new CustomeAdapter(getActivity()));
           //getActivty is used instead of Context
         return view;
    }
  }
```

Refer [this link](http://sogacity.com/how-to-make-a-custom-arrayadapter-for-listview/) & [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8166802/1450401) to know how to create custom adapter

Note : do not use List fragment or List activity to create custom listview

EDIT

```
 ListView yourListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
//Here items must be a List<Items> according to your class instead of String[] array
ListAdapter listadapter = new ListAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items)
ListView.setAdapter( listAdapter);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get an error at -> listview.setadapter(new CustomeAdapter());    "The constructor ListAdapter() is undefined"

Comment: How do I use my own list design? With a custom adapter?

Comment: did you refer the links i given in answer . it gives answer to your question. Inside the getView() method of your custom adapter class you can implement your list design by inflating your item layout for your listview .

Comment: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setAdapter(ListAdapter) from the type ListView" "The constructor ListAdapter(FragmentActivity) is undefined"

Comment: The character 'v' in Listview should be changed to ListView.

Comment: (Listview)  --> (ListView). You still forgot one.

Comment: @Stallman my dear friend we are humans mistakes happens .If you find a mistake you can edit it  .I will take care of it .and is this because of this you down-vote my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
public class fragmentpassword extends Fragment {

        String[] name={"A","B","C","D"};
        int [] image={R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.drawable.ic_drawer};

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutpassword, container, false);

            ListView li=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listViewPassword);
            li.setAdapter(new PasswordAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.passwordlay,name));
            return v;
        }

        class PasswordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

            public PasswordAdapter(Context context, int resource, String[] objects) {
                super(context, resource, objects);
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v=((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.passwordlay,null);
                TextView txt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewpasslay);
                  txt1.setText(name[position]);
                ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageViewpasslay);
                img.setBackgroundResource(image[position]);

                return v;
            }
        }
    }


    **XML for customlist: passwordlay.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageViewpasslay" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textViewpasslay"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    **XML for fragment:  layoutpassword.xml**

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewPassword"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fragments don't use `setContentView(int)`, so you can't use that, use the `inflater` in `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)` and return the view inflated. As for `findViewById(int)` do it like this `getActivity().findViewById(int)`.

Comment: Thank you! I still not working, but I understand a lot more now. What about this error?   "The constructor ArrayAdapter(ListActivity, int, String[]) is undefined"